# "what year" or "in what year"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Tell me please which question is correct:

> **What year** did the song come out?
>
> **In what year** did the song come out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are perfectly idiomatic. Generally speaking the inclusion or exclusion of **in** in such questions will depend mainly on the context.

The preposition really means **in the course of what year**. So people are more likely to ask:

> What year do you plan to retire?
>
> What year might you join us at Christmas?

when the actual year rather than any month of the year is indicated.

On the other hand, the likely inclusion of **in** might occur in sentences such as:

> In what year did the first symptoms of the disease appear?
>
> In what year did you begin to lose your hair?

Here the question means: During the course of which year.

However, the choice is as much a matter of preference as of context. In your examples you could as easily include the preposition as omit it.